# How to use combinators with zip iterable

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

The zip that accepts iterable is turning my object to Object[] vs the merge.  After the zip, I cannot perform other transformation because I lost my object type.  Is this the same concept as the stream's reduce combiner?  Just wondering how to properly use it.  Thanks.

```
final List<Object[]> list = Flux
        .zip(List.of(Mono.just("hello"), Mono.just("world")), objects -> objects)
        .collectList().block();

final List<String> strings = Flux
        .merge(List.of(Mono.just("hello"), Mono.just("world")))
        .collectList().block();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an API limitation at present since the generic type of the Iterable's `Publisher` isn't captured, so that type information isn't available to you in the method. This means you'll unfortunately have to do *something* unsafe if you want to keep the type information here.

The most trivial change to your current code to get a `List<String[]>` would be the following:

```
final List<String[]> list = Flux
        .zip(List.of(Mono.just("hello"), Mono.just("world")), objects -> Arrays.stream(objects).toArray(String[]::new))
        .collectList().block();
```

...but of course, you do lose your type safety.

Depending on your use case (generally speaking, if you combinator can combine elements one at a time rather than all in one go), you may also be able to use `Flux.zip()` in a reducer:

```
List<Flux<String>> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(Flux.just("hello", "me"));
l.add(Flux.just("world", "hungry"));

final List<String> strings = Flux.fromIterable(l)
        .reduce((a, b) -> Flux.zip(a, b, (x, y) -> x + ", " + y))
        .flatMap(x -> x.collectList())
        .block();
```

It's not equivalent, but may be a type-safe alternative depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the first argument to the zip function takes a `Iterable<? extends Publisher<?>>` the question marks mean it can take whatever object.

and its second argument `Function<? super Object[],? extends O>` is a function that the first argument is "something" that is an object in an array, and the second argument is "something" that extends a concrete type.

So sadly you will be getting a `Object[]` it's how it is written. You can cast your objects to the correct.

I have never used it before but i played around with it a bit.

```
final Flux<String> helloWorldString = Flux.zip(List.of(Mono.just("hello"), Mono.just(" "), Mono.just("world")), objects -> {
        StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();
        for (var object : objects) {
            value.append((String) object);
        }

        return value.toString();
    });
```

As it is a combinator i think its purpose is to take any `objects[]` and build a concrete type out if it.